# Sub report in Crystal report is not showing the applied property in server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm generating the Report using Crystal Report and I have the Sub report, In the sub report I have some Date fields and some money fields and comments fields as well.
I have given following Properties for the fields:

```
1: Date fields = march 31, 2012
2: Money fields = $(1000,00 )
3: Comments = can grow true
```

Now the thing is, if I generate the report in Local machine then Everything works fine but same report if I generate in Server then the property which I have given is not applying.

Comment: What "property" is not applying? Update your answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this bahaviour on date and number fields. Use a custom format even if the desired output is available in the format list.